# Package was found but does not support schematics

Tags: angular, firebase, angular13

In Angular 13 , ng add @angular/fire, is giving this error -> "Package "@angular/fire" was found but does not support schematics."

PS C:\Users\laksh\webdev\angular> ng add @angular/fire
Skipping installation: Package already installed
Package "@angular/fire" was found but does not support schematics.
PS C:\Users\laksh\webdev\angular>

Answer (score 0):

Try running the firebase tools:

```
npm i -D firebase-tools
```

The code above is from [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3105)

then install firebase using:

```
npm install firebase @angular/fire --force
```

Comment: i tried it , still facing the error

Comment: Try the edited answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by updating my package json to the latest version:

```
{
  "name": "career-portfolio",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.2.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.4"
  }
}
```

https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus/issues/69